# How asynchronous render dom in Vue file?

Tags: vue.js

I use `$refs.height[index].offsetTop` in the 1st part to computed same values, but $refs.height is in the 2rd part ,that render after the 1st part,so reload page has error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

I try comment  `<div>{{showNumber(index)}}</div>`,then `run npm dev`,then recomment , it's work.

How render the 2rd part at first?

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    //1st part 
    <div id="catalog">
      <div v-for="(baike,index) in baikes">
        <div class="catalog">
          <h2>{{index+1}}.{{baike.name}}</h2>
          <hr style="border:1px dashed #000; flex-grow: 1">
          <div>{{showNumber(index)}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    //2rd part
    <div id="content">
      <div v-for="(baike,index) in baikes" ref="height">
        <h3 >{{index+1}}.{{baike.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{baike.abstract}}</p>
        <ul v-for="(info,key,index) in baike.info">{{key}}-{{info}}</ul></ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import baikeJSON from '../../items.json'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      baikes: baikeJSON,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    showNumber(i){
      return Math.ceil(this.$refs.height[i].offsetTop/1000)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide complete fiddle for your case?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jr7uL5ez/10/

Answer (score 0):

Switch 2rd part and 1st part of position then add css

```
#app{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
```